# Proving a solution satisfying $y'(0)=0$ is even

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y''+a(x)y'+b(x)y=0$ is an ODE such that $a(x),b(x)$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, the function $a(x)$ is odd and $b(x)$ is even. Prove that a solution satisfying $y'(0)=0$ is even.

My initial idea was to show that $y(-x)$ is a solution, and by uniqueness theorem we get $y(x)=y(-x)$ for a certain solution satisfying $y'(0)=0$ and some other initial condition $y(0)=y_0$. However I'm not sure about this. Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. What went wrong when you tried it? Remember to apply the chain rule when differentiating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u(x)=y(x)-y(-x)$, then $u'(x)=y'(x)+y'(-x)$ and $u''(x)=y''(x)-y''(-x)$.

We are given
$$
y''(x)+a(x)y'(x)+b(x)y(x)=0\tag{1}
$$
Plugging in $-x$
$$
y''(-x)-a(x)y'(-x)+b(x)y(-x)=0\tag{2}
$$
Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ gives
$$
u''(x)+a(x)u'(x)+b(x)u(x)=0\tag{3}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
u''(0)&=y''(0)-y''(0)=0\\
u'(0)&=y'(0)+y'(0)=0\\
u(0)&=y(0)-y(0)=0
\end{align}\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply that $u(x)\equiv0$, and $y$ is even.